# Woocommerce - Disable image change on variation select

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a way to disable image change on variation select of a variable product?

I know that you can simple remove the image from variation but in my case this isn't an option because i need the variation images.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commenting out anything in WooCommerce plugin files isn't the most rational solution, because whenever WooCommerce pushes an update that changes that file, your changes are lost.

WooCommerce uses wc_variations_image_update method nowadays (11/2023). Hijacking the method removes the functionality of image change on variation selectiton.

```
jQuery(($) => {
    $.fn.wc_variations_image_update = () => {
      //Do nothing
    }
});
```

Comment: After a long time, finally a clean answer! Works like a charm, thank you very much!

Comment: @Billy Glad it works for you. I've also looked for different solutions and this seems to be the only one that works (besides editing the WooCommerce files).

Answer (score 3):

I'm posting a solution, not the perfect one, but is something.
In WooCommerce/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart-variation.min file you can comment `i.$form.wc_variations_image_update(a)` and this will make variation image update on selection.

Comment: This breaks woocommerce ability to show the price

Comment: Maybe it happened now with the latest update, I'm not sure. Either way, as I mentioned before, it is not the perfect solution and I haven't found the right one yet.

Comment: My most straightforward solution is to add a hidden product image to the first place in the product-image.php file and apply display: none; on that image.